# How to hide some elements in JSX

Tags: react-native, hide, reactjs

I want to display on my app a list of meal 'tags'. So based on the code below, I was able to do that. So as a result of the code, I will get a list or a set of mealTags displayed.

Question: I want to only show the first 2 tags, hide the rest and put a link 'show more where the rest will appear when I click it . How can I do this in ReactJS?

```
return (
  <View {...otherprops} style={styles.mainContainer} elevation={3}>
    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
      <MealTagsSection mealTags={post.mealTags} />
    </View>
```

---

```
type MealTagsProps = {
  mealTags: Array<MealTag>;
};

export function MealTagsSection(props: MealTagsProps) {
  let {mealTags} = props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.mealTagsContainer}>
      {
        mealTags.map((mealTag) => {
          let tagStyle = '';
          if (mealTag.category === 1) {
            tagStyle = styles.tag_healthy;
          } else {
            tagStyle = styles.tag_improve;
          }
          return (
            <View style={tagStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.tagText}>{mealTag.description}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set visible count in state

```
this.state= {
   visibleCount:2
}
```

and use slice function before map, for example

```
mealTags.slice(0, this.state.visibleCount).map(...)
```

Then you can increase visible count as you want in button onClick funtion.

Comment: Thanks @Ahbishek. Can I also get advise on how I can check and display a 'load more' link only if there are hidden tags? Can I do it the mealtagssection function?

Comment: You can check put a flag before loade more link, `{this.state.visibleCount<mealTags.length && <LoadMoreComponent />}`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to track the index in your `.map` block

```
 mealTags.map((mealTag, idx) => ...
```

and style accordingly e.g. `display:none` when idx >= 2